# psycopg2.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type record to geometry

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, postgis

I've a query that find nearest POI from a linestring. The query is like this:

```
import psycopg2

conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=TestGIS user=postgis")
cur = conn.cursor()

cur.execute("SELECT poi.name,poi.city,ST_AsTEXT(poi.the_geog),
            ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(road.the_geog::geometry, poi.the_geog::geometry)),
            ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_ClosestPoint(road.the_geog::geometry, poi.the_geog::geometry), poi.the_geog::geometry)/1000 
            AS Distance FROM road, poi WHERE road.id = 123 AND
            ST_DWithin(road.the_geog, poi.the_geog, 1000.0) ORDER BY
            ST_LineLocatePoint(road.the_geog::geometry, poi.the_geog::geometry), 
            ST_Distance(road.the_geog, poi.the_geog);")
```

Now I want to execute the same query but the linestring(road) is provided in the same query. Something like this:

```
cur.execute("
    SELECT
        poi.name,poi.city,ST_AsTEXT(poi.the_geog),
        ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(road::geometry, poi.the_geog::geometry)),
        ST_Distance_Sphere(ST_ClosestPoint(road::geometry, poi.the_geog::geometry), poi.the_geog::geometry)/1000 AS Distance
    FROM (
        SELECT ST_GeographyFromText(
            'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(85.280194 23.296728,85.281572 23.297479)'
            )
        ) AS road, poi
    WHERE
        ST_DWithin(road, poi.the_geog, 1000.0) ORDER BY
        ST_LineLocatePoint(road::geometry, poi.the_geog::geometry), 
        ST_Distance(road, poi.the_geog);
")
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: cannot cast type record to geometry
LINE 1: ...sTEXT(poi.the_geog),ST_AsText(ST_ClosestPoint(road::geometry...
```

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong ?

UPDATE:
The table is :

```
cur.execute("CREATE TABLE poi(gid serial PRIMARY KEY, name varchar, city varchar, the_geog geography(POINT,4326) );")
cur.execute('''INSERT INTO poi (gid, name, city, the_geog) VALUES (%s,%s, %s,ST_GeogFromText(%s))''',(int(count),row[0],row[1],coordinates))
```

Comment: Post the Python code

Comment: I'll have a look into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the column an alias so you can refer to it:

```
FROM (
    SELECT ST_GeographyFromText(
        'SRID=4326;LINESTRING(85.280194 23.296728,85.281572 23.297479)'
    ) as road
) AS road
```

Comment: Can you also explain the difference between `as` and `AS` or they are same ?

Comment: @Rahul. You mean the casing? Postgresql keywords are not case sensitive. `as` is optional.